# Firefox: Delete history containing /foo/

Tags: firefox, browser

I want to delete all entries of the history of firefox which contain the term `/424/`.

I can list all matching entries:

[image]

But I could not find a way to delete all these entries at once.

Is there a way to delete all entries containing a term at once?

Comment: do you need more details or another way of @pLumo answer that don't let you deliver that bounty? You had accepted his answer, but there is no comment to ask more details :/

Comment: @damadam I gave the bounty now to pLumo. His answer works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Library Menu in Firefox pasting the following in the address bar:

```
chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul
```

You can open the same in a new Window using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

This is a more advanced site for seeing your Bookmarks and History. Here you can search and mark multiple entries (select all with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

[image: Library Menu]